# A quote whose file's corrupted

Tags: anagram, quote

> Here ter miase nt rivey deremanom’s feci heln we shut dlime hey ttick fs oritthouy ao t tabordinaub s. -Toythim hanZ

Hint:

> The author’s first name is Timothy

Can you recover the original quote?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The unscrambled quote:

> There are times in every commander's life when he must yield the stick of authority to a subordinate. Timothy Zahn
>
> Each word in the original quote has its first letter moved to the next word, and then the letters are scrambled.

Comment: Did you use the hint?

Comment: No the hint was not necessary.

Comment: ...except the rule doesn't hold for the actual author signature, which kind of invalidates the hint?

Comment: @BmyGuest, toythin hanz, sounds like a real name though.